# What is the meaning of preferred in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, methods, prefix, pane

Often when I'm coding in javafx, and using different graphical user interfaces and panes, I come across the word pref, as a prefix to method names, sometimes in contrast to a max/min prefix for the same method name. Sometimes pref behaves weirdly. This may be because I'm not using the pane correctly, or because I'm misinterpreting what the "pref" methods do. Can someone explain what is meant by pref, and what it does in terms of code. I'm just started learning coding, so please break it down in the simplest way possible.

Comment: To understand what this means/does you need to understand how the underlying layout management system works.  Depending on how the layout manager been used works, it may take into consideration the min, pref, and/or max size when making determinations about how it and other components need to be sized.  These are generally "hints" provided to the system, but the system can ignore some or all of them.  The idea of "preferred" is to say, when everything else is equal, I'd like to be this size, but I could also shrink down to `min` or expand to `max` if you support it

Comment: Note that there are methods with different functionality/purpose: setters and getters for the preferred x/y dimension of the node and `prefHeight(double)`/`prefWidth(double)` to compute these values. Layouts use the latter ones, but for `Region`s usually the result depends on the values of the corresponding properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is because an UI system generally let applications request for a size that may not be possible to obtain. Just think of an application requesting for a window of size 10000x10000 but the host UI system can manage such (because the screen size is 400x400 for example), then you will be served for only 400x400.

A good UI application must not enforce sizes or anything like that, but request for sizes and then behave according to what the host gave in return.